# Feed two matrices into an mlp neural network

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, dqn

So Im trying to train a recommender system (w/ DQN) using two sets of data , first is a 2D array size $N\times N$ where the diagonal is the current content (= state) and the rest row is the correlation between them in $[0,1]$ and the second $N\times N$ array has the content's cost
for example:

```
cost : tensor([[0, 0, 1, 1],
              |[1, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 1],
              [1, 0, 1, 0]])
Content: tensor([[0.0000, 0.1521, 0.8630, 0.0475],
                 [0.1521, 0.0000, 0.3607, 0.3768],
                 [0.8630, 0.3607, 0.0000, 0.2905],
                 [0.0475, 0.3768, 0.2905, 0.0000]])
```

How should i manage the data to input them to an MLP, my state size and the action size are the same $N$.

Comment: I think you can flatten the matrices to obtain a vector